# Multiple Forms in same page ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I working on my first ASP.net MVC project and and i got some problems using multi forms in same page.
First i have created 2 partial Class :
  (*Register will allow user to register, 
   *Login it allow user to login.)

Then i used HTML.render to integrate them in my "Logpage".
So i have To uses 2 different Action. Like this one:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LogModel.Login Model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (LogModel.Login.Verifuser(Model.IDUser, Model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Model.IDUser, false);
                if (LogModel.Login.IsAdmin(Model.IDUser, Model.Password))
                {
                    return View("Admin/Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Agence/Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalide username or Password");
                return View(Model);
            }
        }
        return View(Model);
    }
```

The problem that on error case i'm redirect to new Page(White page contain validation summary). So i'm wondring how to show this error message in my default page Logpage.

Comment: Post your code. Follow the formatting guides for instructions on how to make it legible.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you're concerned about the form POST action, you can certainly have both forms POST to different controller actions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can solve this with three actions and a complex model.

```
 public class LoginOrRegisterViewModel
 {
      public Models.RegisterViewModel Register { get; set; }
      public Models.LoginViewModel Login { get; set; }
 }


 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Login()
 {
      return View("Login", new LoginOrRegisterViewModel());
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Register(Models.LoginViewModel model)
 {
      if(!ModelState.IsValid)
           return View("Login", new LoginOrRegisterViewModel(){ Register = model });
      else
      {
           //TODO: Validate the user
           //TODO: Write a FormsAuth ticket
           //TODO: Redirect to somewhere
     }
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Login(Models.RegistrationViewModel model)
 {
      if(!ModelState.IsValid)
           return View("Login", new LoginOrRegisterViewModel(){ Login = model});
      else
      {
           //TODO: CRUD for registering user
           //TODO: Write forms auth ticket
           //TODO: Redirect
     }
 }
```

In your code, make sure that you set the action of the Form:

```
 @model Models.LoginOrRegisterViewModel

 @using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm"}))
 {
       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Login)
 }

 @using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerForm"}))
 {
       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Register)
 }
```

Comment: FYI, your second POST method should be called Register.

Comment: This part """ public class LoginOrRegisterViewModel
 {
      public Models.RegisterViewModel Register {get;set;}
      public Models.LoginViewModel Login {get;set;}  """ where i put it in My Model Class ???
 }

Comment: Also What's ""LoginOrRegister"

Comment: I updated the second POST method to Register, Tuan was correct, it was a typo. LoginOrRegisterViewModel is a Class which is a Model or ViewModel. These usualy go in your Models folder. "LoginOrRegister" should have been "LoginOrRegisterViewModel", I refactored my code before I submitted it and didn't double check all names before submitting. There is also a way to share one controller action for two seperate forms but it's dirty and involves looping through the ModelState and removing errors unrelated to the form that did the submission. I would stick with splitting the actions

Comment: Can you explain me this part :

`@model Models.LoginOrRegisterViewModel

 @using(Html.BeginForm("Login","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm"}))
 {
       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Login)
 }

 @using(Html.BeginForm("Register","Controller",FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerForm"}))
 {
       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Register)
 }`


The error that apear is : `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '+ J2V.Models.LogModel LoginOrRegisterViewModel' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'J2V.Models.LogModel preRegister +'.`

Also i'm using partial view.

Comment: The error is telling you that the view(s) are expecting one type of model and that your controller action is passing a different kind of mode. What is "preRegister" model?

Comment: preRegister model allow me to do validation and some other action. so how to slove this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting the point. A view can only have a single type of a model. You can pass a model type to a view that expects some other sort of model. In my example, I have a complex view model that combines two different simple models and i called it LoginOrRegisterViewModel. This view model handels data both for the Registration and the Login form.

Comment: you need to prefix the binding on the controller signature

Comment: For me, I had to have as input parameter LoginOrRegisterViewModel on both POST methods. Just having one of the underlying ones (register/login viewModel) as parameter gave null values inside the model.

Comment: Are you expecting validation to work when using this construct? I'm running into problems as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64147534).

Comment: I sure am glad you posted this—I ran into the same thing, and, being new to MVC, had no idea where to go. Five years later, you saved my hide :-) | @CularBytes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also need to call IsAdmin in the !Verifyuser branch, to have it return the correct view:

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (LogModel.Login.Verifuser(Model.IDUser, Model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Model.IDUser, false);
                if (LogModel.Login.IsAdmin(Model.IDUser, Model.Password))
                {
                    return View("Admin/Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Agence/Index");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalide username or Password");

                if (LogModel.Login.IsAdmin(Model.IDUser, Model.Password))
                    return View("Admin/Index", Model);
                else
                    return View("Agence/Index", Model);

            }
        }
```

Currently, you're calling `return View(Model);` when you have a ModelState error, which returns the default view for the action, called "Login".

Comment: this didn't Work there is confision beetwen Model

Comment: Then you need to cast Model to the type expected by the Index views, or construct it, and pass it instead Model to View("Admin/Index") and View("Agence/Index").

Comment: I'm beginer i ASP.net MVC can u explain me more ?? i did'nt get the point :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple forms posted to a controller action simultaneously, create a JSON object with client JS that has a separate property for each form and give each of those properties a camel-case name that corresponds to a respective ProperCase parameter of your controller action.  Then, send in a serialization of that JSON object to your controller:

```
let form1 = $('#my-form1-id');
let form2 = $('#my-form2-id');
let url = 'myArea/myController/myAction'
let viewData = {
    controllerParameter1: form1,
    controllerParameter2: form2
};

$.ajax({

    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(viewData),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#my-submit-button-id').html('<i class="fa fa-2x fa-cog fa-spin"></i>');
        $('#my-submit-button-id').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
    success: function (res) {
        alert("Submitted!");
    },
    error: function (status, err) {
        alert("Failed!");
    },
    complete: function (status, err) {

        $('#my-submit-button-id').html('Submit My 2 Forms');
    }
});
```

That should work for a controller action w/ a signature similar to:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(ViewModel1 controllerParameter1, ViewModel2 controllerParameter2)
{
    // do amazing things
}
```