# ValidationSummary() not displaying when using RenderPartial in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When I use

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("Login");}
```

inside my main view, the  `@Html.ValidationSummary()` doesn't work, but when I copy the code from "Login" inside main view, it works.

Why is that, and how do I display validation messages from the partial view?

Here is partial view "Login":

```
@model NyNo.Models.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Username" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })

        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Hope you understand, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot work. A Partial is just a string.

While RenderPartial actually 'writes' the partial markup rather than sending a string back to the View Generator, it does not rebind your View to a new model. If you want Validation Summary to work it must be bound to a model in your main View.

Comment: Allright, I'll take that as an answer, thanks!
My problem now is that I want my login code above and a register form on the same page, but I can't have 2 model references at the top of the View, like this: 
model NyNo.Models.LoginMode
model NyNo.Models.RegisterModel

Any simple solution on this problem?

Comment: @Lars that's a good question. You should create a new post explaining in detail.

Comment: @Lars You can solve the problem of multiple models in a view by creating a complex model that contains the submodels. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9998040/649497 for a good example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related to this (maybe you aren't showing the ViewData passed in the `RenderPartial()`): [Pass Additional ViewData to an ASP.NET MVC 4 Partial View While Propagating ModelState Errors](http://www.codenoevil.com/pass-additional-viewdata-asp-net-mvc-4/)

I was having a similar issue and I solved it this way: [ValidationSummary inside a partial view not showing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935586/1204249)