# Multiple forms on MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have what I hope is a simple question.  I am trying to use multiple forms on an MVC view (like at [Multiple Forms in same page ASP.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997874/multiple-forms-in-same-page-asp-net-mvc)) - each calling different actions on the same controller.  My issue is that any form where I call an action that is named different from the view I get an error.  Simple example below:

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form -horizontal" }))
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">index</button>
}
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("foobar", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form -horizontal" }))
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">foobar</button>
}
```

testController

```
public class testController : Controller
{
    // GET: test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult IndexPost()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult foobar()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Clicking the "index" button works (does nothing)
Clicking the "foobar" button throws an error

```
The view 'foobar' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
```

I am obviously missing something - any wisdom is appreciated

Comment: `return View("Index");` in both POST methods

Comment: When using `return view();` the controller automatically looks for a view with the same name as the action, so it is looking in the views folder for `foobar.cshtml` which probably doesn't exist. As mentioned if you add the view name parameter the `foobar` action will return the index view instead.

Comment: Thanks! return View("Index") works in this example.. this is obviously a simple test, let me try this with my real model based stuff and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost()
{
    return View("Index");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult foobar()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```