# Get Input of second form in MVC page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've built a page, where master and details(pictures, aso) are shown on one page. However, if the submitt button for the second form is clicked, the form is not submitted, if validations in the first form fail. If I correct the values, the `HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile` is null.

The page looks like this:

```
@model app1.Models.MasterModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form-inline col-lg-12" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        <h4>MasterModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


        <div class="row">
            @*Master properties*@

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                 @* aso... *@

                </div>
            </div>


}


            @*  Master Details *@

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">



                @using (Html.BeginForm("NewPic", "Master", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> <!-- First Button, does not work -->

                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        @foreach (app1.Models.PicModel b in Model.Pics)
                        {

                            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(b.DbPic);
                            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);


                <img src="@imgSrc" width="200" height="200" />
                        }
                    </div>


                    @Html.ActionLink("Upload", "NewPic", new { id = Model.Id }) <!-- Second Button, does not work either -->
                    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-4" for="Title">Picer</label>
                }
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>




@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult NewPic(int id, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
         // uploadFile is null
    }
```

Comment: You have a nested form. which submit button are you clicking?

Comment: split them into two partial views , may this will help to solve your issue, and this will help to make your code more clear

Comment: try to use ajax form , this will more helpful for the second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgotten to put **[HttpPost]** before NewPic method. So **NewPic** method will be considered as [HttpGet] so it will not work.

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult NewPic(int id, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
     // uploadFile is null
}
```

And also give proper Id to both form as follow so it would be easy to work with this both while client side validation.

**Form 1**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {id = "Form1", @class = "form-inline col-lg-12" }))
```

**Form 2**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewPic", "Master", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "Form2", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

For more information visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998040/2798643)