# Validation failing when using multiple forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using [this construct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9998040) to host multiple forms in the same view:

[image]

When I submit the first form without entering credentials, validation fails. The form reloads as a GET, with a URL of `/home/signin`, and the expected error messages don't display.

The controller's `ModelState` is invalid as expected, but I can't figure out why this state isn't passed back to the view.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get validation to work with multiple forms?

Here's my code:

---

**Controller**

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports Website.ViewModels.Home
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

Namespace Controllers.Home
  Partial Public Class HomeController
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Function Index() As ActionResult
      Dim oViewModel As SignInOrSignUp

      oViewModel = New SignInOrSignUp

      Return Me.View("Index", oViewModel)
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
    Public Async Function SignIn(Model As SignIn) As Task(Of ActionResult)
      Dim oViewModel As SignInOrSignUp
      Dim eStatus As SignInStatus
      Dim oAction As ActionResult

      oViewModel = New SignInOrSignUp With {.SignIn = Model}

      If Me.ModelState.IsValid Then
        eStatus = Await Me.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Model.Username, Model.Password, isPersistent:=False, shouldLockout:=False)

        If eStatus = SignInStatus.Success Then
          oAction = Me.Redirect("www.domain.com")
        Else
          Me.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid signin attempt.")
          oAction = Me.View("Index", oViewModel)
        End If
      Else
        oAction = Me.View("Index", oViewModel)
      End If

      Return oAction
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

**ViewModel**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Namespace ViewModels.Home
  Public Class SignIn
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="User Name is required.")>
    <Display(Name:="User Name")>
    Public Property Username As String

    <Required>
    Public Property Password As String

    <Display(Name:="Remember Me")>
    Public Property RememberMe As Boolean
  End Class
End Namespace
```

**View**

```
@ModelType ViewModels.Home.SignInOrSignUp

@Code
  Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Website</title>
  @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/bootstrap")
  @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery")
  @Styles.Render("~/styles/bootstrap")
  @Styles.Render("~/styles/home")
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="section">
        <h5>Sign in here</h5>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="titlebar">Sign In</div>
          @Using (Html.BeginForm("signin", "home", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "SignInForm"}))
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(M) Model.SignIn)
            @<div class="button">
              <input type="submit" value="Sign In" Class="button" />
            </div>
            @<div class="anchor">
              <a href="/">Forgot your password?</a>
            </div>
          End Using
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <h5>Or enter your City Code here</h5>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="titlebar">Sign Up</div>
          @Using (Html.BeginForm("signup", "home", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "SignUpForm"}))
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(M) Model.SignUp)
            @<div class="button">
              <input type="submit" value="Continue" Class="button" />
            </div>
          End Using
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**--EDIT--**

I've been able to get unblocked in the meantime with a clunky workaround in my view:

```
@Code
  If IsPost AndAlso Request.Path = "/home/signin" AndAlso Model.SignIn.Username.IsNothing Then
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) Model.SignIn.Username, "Username is required", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
  End If
End Code
```

But I'd still like to use the in-built validation mechanism if it's possible to do so with multiple forms in the same view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you can try:

**1. Put validation summary on the page:**

With this option you are not changing anything in your controller but you are putting error summary on your page. You will not get highlighted field but you will still be able to display all errors, like:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
      @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Not an elegant solution!

**2. In controller use `SignInOrSignUp` as an input but from UI provide either `SignIn` or `SignUp` model:**

With this approach you are not changing your vbhtml/cshtml file it will remain as it is only thing you are changing is type of argument on controller methods:

```
Namespace Controllers.Home
  Partial Public Class HomeController
    ...
    <HttpPost>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
    Public Async Function SignIn(Model As SignInOrSignUp) As Task(Of ActionResult)
       ...
    End Function
        
    <HttpPost>
    Public Async Function SignUp(Model As SignInOrSignUp) As Task(Of ActionResult)
       ...
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

unless there is some complex validation involved, this approach will work like a charm!

Comment: That works, thank you (#2). I'll send the bounty as soon as the website will let me do so. In the meantime, I'm curious about something. You say *"from UI provide either SignIn or SignUp model,"* but how am I doing this? Is it here: `Html.BeginForm("signin", "home", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "SignInForm"})`? If so, that would seem odd, as there's no mention of a model there—just an `Action` and a `Controller`.

Comment: Actually you are when you are using any fields inside form and submit the form, that form bill be submitted and not any other forms on the page. Hence you are only sending sign-in/signup model data to server.

Comment: Aha. That explains it, thanks. The model binder is smarter than me :-)